# Samsung i7500 Galaxy - speakers, calling problem after listening music

Tags: android, call, speaker, android-hardware

I've been listening music on my Samsung i7500 Galaxy with headset plugged to the device. After listening I've plugged headset out and now while I call to somebody I see there is a call on the device screen, but either me, either person whom I am calling to, doesn't hear the other person. While I plug headset again I can hear everything (on the headset), after another plug out problem still exist. Anybody know how to fix it?

I found this [solution](http://androidforums.com/samsung-i7500/41993-speakers-problem.html), but it doesn't works in my case.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it's a problem with using task killers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should be asked on superuser.com. I move this issue to the proper place:

[Samsung i7500 Galaxy - speakers, calling problem after listening music](https://superuser.com/questions/208900/samsung-i7500-galaxy-speakers-calling-problem-after-listening-music)